# How can I link to a stack screen from inside a tab layout in expo router?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo-router

My app structure is

/app

- index (and others)
- _layout
- /settings

  - _layout (simple `export default Stack` from expo-router)
  - index

[image: App folder structure]

Root layout (`app/_layout`) gives bottom tabs navigation.
[image: Tab bar navigation]

From here I want the settings tab to load `/settings/index`
This is the code I have but tab press takes me nowhere.

```
          <Tabs.Screen
            name="settings"
            options={{
              href: '/settings',
              title: 'Settings',
              tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
                <Settings color={color} size={size} />
              ),
            }}
          />
```

If I change the href from '/settings' to '/settings/index' I get `Unmatched Route` exception.

If I change `<Tabs.Screen` to `<Stack.Screen` the linking and navigation works good but I cant control the tab bar icon or tab screen heading.

Comment: Can you share a reproducible demo of your app? Maybe the problem is in other part.